# How to check if an item in a ChoiceField is selected?

Tags: django

In a form I want to use a list that contains all items from a ChoiceField that have *not* been selected yet. In order to do this I want to iterate through the choices and discard the ones that are selected (i.e. have selected="selected" in their html)

```
class MethodForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MethodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #pseudo-code starts here
        exclude = []
        for val in self.fields['someM2Mfield'].choices:
            exclude.append(val.is_selected)
        #/pseudocode
        rule_choices = get_rule_choices(exclude)
        self.fields['rule'] = forms.ChoiceField(rule_choices)
        ...
```

The pseudocode bit is where I don't know what methods/properties to use. Can anyone enlighten me?

PS: I am able to iterate through the choices by calling `next()` on `self.fields[].choices.__iter__`, but how do I determine whether the choice is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form's `self.inital` should give you a dictionary with the initial values for all fields of the form. So `self.initial['someM2Mfield']` should return the already selected *values*. If you need the list of selected *choices* you might do something like:

```
selected_values = self.initial['someM2Mfield']
rule_choices = [(value, text) for value, text in 
                self.fields['someM2Mfield'].choices
                if value in selected_values]
```

Comment: This only works on existing forms. When I add a new form (MethodForm is part of a formset), the existing values are still excluded, but the value in the newly added form is not. Any ideas how I can include those too?

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution based on your answer + some home brew of myself for the case of a new form.